# Where is my Goddess Chest from the Goddess Cube in the volcano?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

When I entered the actual volcano in Eldin Volcano and dove off the metal platform, I landed on a tall rock platform witha  Goddess Cube on it. I hit it witha  Skyward Strike and it shot into the sky, but when I returned to the sky to open the Goddess Chest, I saw no indication of where it was on my map!

What gives? I've struck at least a half dizen other Goddess Cubes and they all showed up on my map in the Sky. Where's my treasure!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably can't see it at the point of the game you're at.  Spoiler alert:

> It's probably in the swirling hurricane area that you can't see through on your map.  You'll be able to enter this area when you get to the songs / lighthouse segment of the game.  Once you enter this area, any goddess chests you have will show up on your map.

Either that, or perhaps it's in Skyloft.  Check your map once you land inside Skyloft.

Comment: Oh, man, I want my treasure *now!* ;-) Thanks for the spoiler tag BTW.

Comment: Haha patience young padawan.  PS I updated my post, it could be in Skyloft.